# Not able to build producation apk

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-proguard

I am getting this error.`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':OfficeChat:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

  > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.`

Comment: Can u post your gradle here

Comment: this error arise when your buildtools version and gradle version different

Comment: check this .https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198963

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that ProGuard has found some warnings that you have to handle in some way before processing can continue.

Normally you should see the warnings in the console log, otherwise you might need to enable additional logging options (like -i for gradle).

Usually the warnings are solved by adding additional required libraries, adding `-dontwarn` rules or using `-ignorewarnings` as a last resort.